# Diode power consumption

Tags: power, current, diodes

I need to convert from 4 to 3.3V. So I was thinking of a diode, or voltage regulator. Voltage regulators, I know that it uses about 5mA to do the job.

How much current a diode uses ? I cant find this information...

[sorry I deleted the former question, was wrong 3.3 not 4.4]

Comment: Could you explain more about what you are doing? What provides the 4 V? What uses the 3.3 V? Why are you concerned about 5 mA? What do you want to achieve here? I can't tell from this and I didn't read your prior, deleted question.

Comment: I'm asking how much current a diode absorb, so I can opt for the diode or a regulator.

Comment: if you're simply putting the diode in series (forward-biased) and using the 0.6v or 0.7v drop of the diode to bring you down to 3.3v, then ***all*** of the current going to your load (is that about 5 mA ?) is going through the diode.  with voltage drop and series current, you can easily calculate the power that the diode will dissipate.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but at this time I currently believe that your mental model of the situation leading to your posed dichotomy still needs some work. I don't think I can offer much help, for now. I wish I could. I just can't see how, for now.

Comment: What is the input source? What is the load current?

Comment: Ok robert, you are saying zero. But what do you mean by "the power that the diode will dissipate" ? Can't I know the current instead of the power ? Or you mean the max power ?

Comment: you do not have a clear understanding of voltage, current and power .... you are totally on the wrong track with the idea of current dissipation ..... the diode does not dissipate current, it dissipates a small amount of power in the form of heat .... the "zero" that you keep talking about is vapor

Comment: Ok Ill ask to you too. Supose that i'm using a battery, will the batt discharge sooner (cos of this voltage/power loss) with the diode than without ?

Comment: The 5mA that you quote is the data sheet quiescent current for the ancient 78L05 (and presumably 3.3V versions), which is old enough to be conscripted into the military, drive, drink, and become President of the United States.  There are three-terminal regulators out there that use a LOT less current.  You want a fixed regulator with quiescent current low enough to suit you, a dropout voltage less than 0.7V, an output voltage of 3.3V, and a current rating high enough to power whatever you're driving.

Comment: So... in this case the diode will dissipate 3.3V * 100 uA = 0,00033 W while the regulator, 3.3V(or 4?) * 5mA = 0,0165 W ? (100uA is the current with the load)

Comment: But like Tim says there are ldo regulators that uses 1uA (Iq). Like the TPS7A05 ? That means 3.3V(or 4?) * 1 uA = 0,0033 W ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to convert from 4 to 3.3V. So I was thinking of a diode, ...

Presumably you are considering using the forward voltage drop, V<sub>f</sub> of a silicon diode placed in series with the load to drop about 0.7 V to bring your voltage down.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQeqiF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Using a diode to reduce supply voltage.*

This works but you need to be aware of a few things:

- It is not a regulator. It just drops voltage and the voltage drop depends on the current. At more than a few mA it typically drops about 0.7 V but at lower currents the voltage drop will decrease. The I-V curve for the diode will help you calculate this.
- If V1 increases or decreases the the load voltage will increase or decrease with it. Again, it's not a regulator.
- The fact that you're looking for 3.3 V suggests that you want to power a micro-controller. You need a regulator.

> ... or voltage regulator. Voltage regulators, I know that it uses about 5 mA to do the job.

- Regulators do require some current to operate.
- Regulators also require some "headroom" - the difference between the input and output voltage - to operate. If you are thinking of a 78xx series regulator then these need about 2 V or so. You don't have that much headroom so you would be looking for a "low drop-out" (LDO) regulator.

> How much current a diode uses?

A diode doesn't "use" current. It *passes* current but reduces the voltage. The power dissipated in the diode can be calculated from \$ P = VI = 0.7 \times I \$.

Comment: Thanks for the usefull information ! So zero ! Thanks at you and robert.

Comment: A question. Supose that i'm using a battery, will the batt discharge sooner (cos of this voltage/power loss) with the diode than without ?

Comment: @Jackt, how can information be useful when it appear that you do not understand it .... if you did, then you would not have said `so zero`.

Comment: Enlight me jsotola then

Comment: @jsotola: I think the OP means that this circuit doesn't require any *additional* current, "so zero".

Comment: The question transistor, comment 2

Answer (score 1):

The diode may be a good choice if your load current and input voltage are fairly stable and known.

Keep in mind that the nominal 0.7V or so drop from the diode will be less at very low current and you'll pretty much get the full input voltage with a very light load. If whatever your load is goes into a sleep mode and the current drops to about zero then you'll see that voltage increase to maybe 3.9V. If that is within specs, then you are okay, but then maybe you don't need the diode at all.

There are various regulators. The [LP5912-3.3DRVT](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp5912.pdf) is one. It can output 500mA with only 0.25V drop (typically less than 50mV at 200mA) and typically draws only about 30uA for its own purposes. It can handle up to 5.5V input.

If you choose to use an LDO regulator, be sure to **carefully** read the section on capacitors and follow it to the letter. In this case, 1uF ceramic capacitors are suitable on both input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Jackt, the answer you are looking for is you can do it either way, the useable life of the battery will be comparable, 99% deteremined by the "load" you have on it.  One small difference you might want to consider, if the battery voltage drops below 4 V, then the same voltage drop will appear after the diode.  If you need a consistent 3.3 V, a regulator would be the better option.